# does onCreate fire any listener - android

Tags: android

I am creating a android library, In that I want to find if the OnCreate of the main application is running? . I dont know whether oncreate fire any listener. Anybody knows will oncreate fires any listener. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what question you are asking...

Comment: I need to watch for any listeners that is created by OnCreate() method.

Comment: i think u answered befor is right, can u please explain me ur answer which u wrote befor Alex, Thanks

Comment: OK, I undeleted it... I thought I misunderstood your question initially but I guess not. I'm not 100% sure what you mean about "are there any listeners fired" but you can check out the source code and see for yourself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this callback does not exist.

The way most libraries introduce this callback is by making a base type that they require another application to call back into. Like you could make your library do something like:

```
public class MyLibBaseApplication extends Application {

   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      // my callback stuff.
   }
}
```

and then require all the users of your library either use or extend your Application object as the Application class in their manifest.  This way sort of sucks for developers though, although there are a few libs that do this. It blocks you from using multiple libs with this same pattern (Super annoying).

Personally I think just asking for a callback from whoever is using the library is probably much better from a client and dev who would integrate a library.

Just a simple call or static function that would be like:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       //register
       YourLibrary.onCreateFired(this);
       // or istantiate and register
       YourLibraryCallback cb = new YourLibraryCallback(this);
       cb.onCreateFired();
    }
}
```

This way I think offers the most flexibility.

Comment: I agree about the "it sucks for users though" part... especially if the user needed to extend `Application` for some other reason (since there can only be one subclass of `Application`).

Comment: I won't mention names, but those library devs know who they are ;)

Comment: I dont want the user to explicitly register from their code to my library, I want to get it automatically by any listeners. Is there any way to do like this

Comment: No, the dev's application is in control, not the other way around.